# Haskell: Understanding the foldl function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am learning about folds from 'Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!' by Miran Lipovaca.

For the following example which uses `foldl`:

```
sum' :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
sum' xs = foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) 0 xs 

ghci> sum' [3,5,2,1]
11
```

I understand that `acc` is the accumulator and `x` is the starting value (the first value from the list `xs`). I don't quite understand how 0 and xs are passed into the lambda function as parameters - how does the function know that the value of `acc` is 0 and the value of `x` is 3? Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: The `foldl` function is equivalent to a for loop. For example, `foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) 0 xs` is equivalent to `acc = 0; for (x of xs) { acc = acc + x; } return acc;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall the definition of `foldl`:

```hs
foldl f acc []     = acc
foldl f acc (x:xs) = foldl f (f acc x) xs
```

Now, the best way to understand folds is to walk through the evaluation. So let's start with:

```hs
sum [3,5,2,1]
== foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) 0 [3,5,2,1]
```

The second line of the definition of the `foldl` function means this is equivalent to the following:

```hs
== foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) ((\acc x -> acc + x) 0 3) [5,2,1]
```

Now since the lambda expression is applied to parameters, `0` and `3` are passed in as `acc` and `x`:

```hs
== foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) (0+3) [5,2,1]
```

And the process repeats:

```hs
== foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) ((\acc x -> acc + x) (0+3) 5) [2,1]
== foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) ((0+3)+5) [2,1]
== foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) ((\acc x -> acc + x) ((0+3)+5) 2) [1]
== foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) (((0+3)+5)+2) [1]
== foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) ((\acc x -> acc + x) (((0+3)+5)+2) 1) []
== foldl (\acc x -> acc + x) ((((0+3)+5)+2)+1) []
```

At this point, evaluation continues according to the first line of the `foldl` definition:

```hs
== ((((0+3)+5)+2)+1)
```

So to answer your question directly: the function knows the values of `acc` and `x` simply because the definition of `foldl` passes their values to the function as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to look at how the `foldl` function is defined:

```
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldl f a []     = a
foldl f a (x:xs) = foldl f (f a x) xs
```

So, if the input list is empty then we just return the accumulator value `a`. However, if it's not empty then we loop. Within the loop, we update the accumulator value to `f a x` (i.e. we apply the lambda function `f` to the current accumulator value and the current element of the list). The result is the new accumulator value.

We also update the value of the list in the loop by removing its first element (because we just processed the first element). We keep processing the remaining elements of the list until there are no elements left, at which point we return the value of the accumulator.

The `foldl` function is equivalent to a for loop in imperative languages. For example, here's how we could implement `foldl` in JavaScript:

```js
const result = foldl((acc, x) => acc + x, 0, [3,5,2,1]);

console.log(result);

function foldl(f, a, xs) {
    for (const x of xs) a = f(a, x);
    return a;
}
```

Hope that elucidates the `foldl` function.

Comment: Closest thing to `foldl` in JavaScript is [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)